Giving TabBarView dynamic height where children are GridView
I am using TabBarView and in children, I have GridView.List(), when I Use Expand(), it gives me the error of

Failed assertion: line 544 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.

I used NestedScrollView with SliverToBoxAdapter but then I get a strange padding from the top, here is my build method
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Container(
  height: h,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
    left: 12,
    right: 0,
    top: 25,
  ),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 40,
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            router.push(
              SearchList.routeName,
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
              right: 12,
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
              border: Border.all(
                color: const Color(0xffE8E8E8),
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(width: 20),
                SvgPicture.asset('svg/search.svg'),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Where are you travelling next?',
                      style:
                          Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelSmall!.copyWith(
                                color: const Color(0xff000000),
                                fontFamily: 'OverUsed',
                                fontSize: 16,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              ),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Anywhere, 30 Days plans",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 11,
                        color: Color(0xffA0A4A8),
                        fontFamily: 'OverUsed',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
          indicator: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                width: 0.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          dividerHeight: 0,
          labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 5,
          ),
          overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),
          tabs: [
            countriesTabContainer(context,
                text: "Popular  ", isSelected: selectedIndex == 0),
            countriesTabContainer(context,
                text: "Destinations", isSelected: selectedIndex == 1),
            countriesTabContainer(context,
                text: "Regions", isSelected: selectedIndex == 2),
          ],
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              selectedIndex = index;
              _tabController?.animateTo(index);
            });
          },
        ),
        Flex(direction: Axis.vertical, children: [
          TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: [
              ProductsGrid(
                type: ProductType.popular,
              ),
              ProductsGrid(
                type: ProductType.country,
              ),
              ProductsGrid(
                type: ProductType.region,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

This is my Product Grid
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var data = context.watch<ProductsListProvider>().byType(widget.type);
return GridView.builder(
  itemCount: data.length,
  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    childAspectRatio: 0.78,
  ),
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 8.0,
        bottom: 8.0,
      ),
      child: TileCard(
        horizontal: 0,
        elevation: 1,
        radius: 13.4,
        onTap: () {
          router.push(PlansPage.routeName, extra: data[index]);
        },
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: NetworkImageWithPlaceholder(
                    data[index].imageUrl,
                    circular: false,
                    width: 193,
                    height: 164,
                    radius: 12,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 8,
                  left: 8,
                  child: NetworkImageWithPlaceholder(
                    data[index].flag,
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    circular: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                data[index].name,
                maxLines: 1,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontFamily: 'OverUsed',
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Starting from: ",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontFamily: 'OverUsed',
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "\$6.00 USD",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall!.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontFamily: 'OverUsed',
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
 );
 }

This is the screenshot from NestedScrollView


Try to set your Gridview and TabBar padding ZERO

I have already tried it, no success

ok, so the answer is that when you do shrinkWrap: true, it adds SliverPaddingProperty to the GridView or ListView, in order to remove this padding, wrap your widget in MediaQuery.removePadding() where you are using shrinkwraping, here is the example
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var data = context.watch<ProductsListProvider>().byType(widget.type);
return MediaQuery.removePadding(
  context: context,
  removeTop: true,
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: data.length,
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      childAspectRatio: 0.82,
    ),
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container();
    },
  ),
);}


